# Geometric transformations with matrix multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus, matrices, trigonometry

Say you have a matrix of position vectors, could someone please explain the intuition behind why a rotation by an angle $\theta$ about the origin can be represented by the matrix:

$$
R= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\ 
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: There is a derivation (x1,y1) = R* (x,y) for coordinates before and after rotation.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The figure represents the two versors of the canonical basis $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$ and the two vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ that we obtain rotating $\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j}$ by an angle $\theta$. You can see that the components of such vectors are
$$
\mathbf{u}=[u_x,u_y]^T=[\cos \theta, \sin \theta]^T \qquad \mathbf{v}=[v_x,v_y]^T=[-\sin \theta, \cos \theta]^T
$$
The matrix tat represent this transformation of the basis has as first column the vector $\mathbf{u}$ ( i.e. the transformed of $\mathbf{i}$) and as second column the transformed of $\mathbf{j}$, i.e. $\mathbf{v}$.

By definition of row-column multiplication you can easily see that the matrix
$$
R=
\begin {bmatrix}
\cos \theta &-\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end {bmatrix}
$$
transforms the basis vectors in $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$ (rotated by $\theta$) and, since any vector is a linear combination of the basis vectors the matrix rotate any vector by an angle $\theta$.

---

How works linearity.

Any vector is a linear combination of the basis vectors: $\mathbf{v}=v_1\mathbf{i}+v_2\mathbf{j}$
so ve have:
$$
R\mathbf{v}=R(v_1\mathbf{i}+v_2\mathbf{j})=v_1R\mathbf{i}+v_2R\mathbf{j}
$$
You can easely see that $|R\mathbf{v}|=|\mathbf{v}|$
 and the angle $\phi$ between $R\mathbf{v}$ and $R\mathbf{i}$ is given by:
$$
\cos \phi=\dfrac{(R\mathbf{v},R\mathbf{i})}{|R\mathbf{v}||R\mathbf{i}|} =\dfrac {v_1}{|R\mathbf{v}|}=\dfrac {v_1}{|\mathbf{v}|}
$$
i.e. the same angle between $\mathbf{v} $ and $\mathbf{i}$.

So, since $R\mathbf{i}$ is rotated by $\theta$ with respect to $\mathbf{i}$,then $R\mathbf{v}$ is rotated by $\theta+\phi$ with respect to $\mathbf{i}$.

Comment: I understand everything up to: "since any vector is a linear combination of the basis vectors the matrix rotate any vector by an angle θ". If you don't mind, could you please expand on that part. Thank you.

Comment: I've added to my answer. I hope it's sufficient.